# Как прочитать URL ресурс в вебсфере из java-кода?

Tags: java, spring, websphere

Приложение написано на spring и развернуто на websphere8.5.5.13(внутри докера, деталей не знаю) 
Сервер представляет собой кластер с парой нод
На кластере добавлены Resource->URL's пути до папок на шаре

Мне требуется прочитать с сервера WebSphere по пути Resources->URL нужные пути из кода java чтобы использовать его как путь до файлов(вычитать значения)
Чтобы прочитать файлы, я применил такой способ:

Я пробовал такой способ

```
InitialContext initCtx1 = new InitialContext();
        URL url1 = (java.net.URL) initCtx1.lookup("java:comp/env/url/Agreement");
```

Однако, под дебагом, в прочитанном объекте java.net.URL кроме как path даже в host\port - записаны null 
Если пытаюсь прочитать файл
File file = new File(url1.file);
file.exists(); //получаю false

Я неправильно настраиваю чтение ресурса или неверно настроен сам ресурс на сервере?

web.xml

```
<resource-ref>
    <description>agreement source</description>
    <res-ref-name>url/Agreement</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>java.net.URL</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
    <res-sharing-scope>Shareable</res-sharing-scope>
</resource-ref>
```

ibm-web-bnd.xml

```
<virtual-host name="default_host" />
<resource-ref name="url/Agreement" binding-name="url/Agreement"/>
```

то как я читаю url

```
 InitialContext initCtx = new InitialContext();
        URL url = (java.net.URL) initCtx.lookup("java:comp/env/url/Agreement");
```

настройка сервера

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

объект URL под дебагом

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Находите классы-контроллеры, и смотрите, какие там url.

Comment: @Bakhuss можете подсказать о каких классах-контроллерах идет речь?

Comment: По поводу настроек webSphere не подскажу. В коде на spring-е есть классы, у которых методы помечены аннотацией `@Controller` или `@RestController`, там указаны url, по которым эти методы откликаются.

Comment: @Bakhuss понял, спасибо. Вопрос коснулся немного другой  темы еще, это jndi ресурсы с сервера